# What was the relationship between Sutton and Mrs. Harshaw?

Tags: character, the-hot-spot

In [*The Hot Spot*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099797/), what was the relationship between the blackmailer Frank Sutton and Mrs. Dolly Harshaw?

Was he blackmailing her or was it the other way around?

Answer (score 1):

Mrs Harsaw was attracted to bad guys. She was of course bored with her old husband so she had a relationship with the local tough guy.

When Maddox arrived at town, she found him more interesting than Sutton so she turned towards Maddox in the first place.

As Maddox's interest was mitigated in her, she continued to frequent Sutton, as a second best - but also as a tool to keep Maddox in check. Besides she was constantly observing Maddox. At the end they lived happily ever after, showing birds of a feather flock together.

Answer (score 0):

She was having an affair with Sutton. We know this because...

> it was her shoe Harry found at Sutton's shack.

Since she was always playing strategy, it's possible she did this to get more information after discovering or because she suspected he was...

> blackmailing Gloria Harper.

Interesting movie.

Comment: Yes, but Sutton also finds out about the bank robbery from Dolly. So who was the blackmailer and who was the blackmailee? Or were they simply two likeminded individuals in cahoots?

Comment: I don't think there was any blackmailing going on (IMHO). I think she took an interest in Harry, and then looked into Gloria when she saw Harry's interest in Gloria 
and that led her to discover that Sutton was blackmailing Gloria. I think she then struck up a physical relationship with Sutton to keep track of what was going on.